# Switching image with a fade in

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm working on a site here:

http://mccarronandco.com/newsite/modena.php

They've now decided they want the pictures to fade in when you click a thumbnail rather than just have the image switch. The current code is:

```
<div id="mainimage">
    <img src="images/modena/2.jpg"  alt="holder"  name="holder" id="holder">
</div>

<div class="gallerycontainer">     
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/modena/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="Modena" name="modena" width="75" height="56" title="Modena" onClick="document.holder.src='images/modena/2.jpg'" >
    </div>
```

Can anyone suggest a way I can achieve this please? I don't know where to start, I got the above code from a forum...

Many thanks,

Andy

Comment: This is just the markup, Where is js/jquery code? Need to see the stuck point.

Comment: Mind putting the relevant JS, CSS & HTML on jsbin.com?

Comment: @Jai I think the js code is inside markup code document.holder.src='images/modena/2.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this is pure JavaScript but have you given any through to using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library?  It has [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods to make this sort of thing very easy.  You would create a function like

```
function fadeImage(imageURL)
{
    $("#holder img").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $("#holder img").attr('src', imageURL);
        $("#holder img").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

and then call it and pass through the URL of the image you want to fade in.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do this. Download the JS file or use a CDN that hosts jQuery and add it to your websites `<head>` section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then add the following code to your `<head>` section :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetImg(URL) {
    //Fade out the Current Image
    $('#holder').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        //Set the new Image URL
        $('#holder').attr('src', URL);
        //Fade In the new image
        $('#holder').fadeIn();
    });
}
</script>
```

And your IMG html will become :

```
<img src="images/modena/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="Modena" name="modena" width="75" height="56" title="Modena" onClick="SetImg('images/modena/2.jpg');" >
```

What this does is bind the `onclick` event of the Img tag to the function `SetImg`, and you pass the URL of the image you wish to set it to. Inside the SetImg function it finds the control with `ID = holder` and sets the `SRC` attribute. And then calls the `fadeIn()` function of that element.

See [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for more information on the API.

Edit : (To answer a comment question)

Code to only fadeIn the new image :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetImg(URL) {
   //Hide current image
   $('#holder').hide();
   //Set the new Image URL
   $('#holder').attr('src', URL);
   //Fade In the new image
   $('#holder').fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This would not work because you would need to fadeOut() the image first before using fadeIn()

Comment: Incorrect, if you do not use the `fadeOut()` prior to `fadeIn()` it simply sets the `display=none` and proceeds with the `fadeIn()` function.

Comment: I did not know this, sorry.  But fading out first will give a nice effect :)

Comment: I've changed my answer to apply the fadeOut as I do agree that it is a better effect. :)

Comment: Thanks for this. How would the code look if I wanted to just fade in the new image, without fading out the old one please?

Comment: I've added a bit to the bottom of my answer to show the code.

Comment: Hi Nunners, I've tried the new code but it doesn't work. See this page:

Comment: My apologies, it appears that the `.fadeIn()` function does not automatically hide the element. I have added the code `$('#holder').hide();` to the function. This should now work correctly. @Pattle sorry for incorrectly trying to correct you. :)

Comment: Thanks Nunners :-) Is there a way to have the new image fade in over the top of the existing image? At the moment it clears to white and then fades in....

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a way with the current simple solution, you should really ask a new question for this and describe in detail what you currently have and what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) jQuery plugin will allow you to cycle trough the images by simply calling the following method whenever the user clicks one of the images.

```
$('#fade').cycle();
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks, but 'THANKS' for all the responses! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to set the CSS for the image-holder as ,

```
#mainimage
{
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

and instead of an `img` tag, use background-image CSS property. And edit this line too,

```
<img src="images/modena/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="Modena" name="modena" width="75" height="56" title="Modena" onClick="document.holder.style.backgroundImage = 'images/modena/2.jpg'" >
```

This way you dont have to include any plugins.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this option to work. I'm not sure how to set the background image on the image holder. Is that what you mean? Thanks, Andy

Comment: Replace `img` tag with `div`. Even thought you can set background-image for `img`, its semantically wrong.